# Write csv files with Byte Order Mark (BOM) using c++?

Tags: c++, file-handling, byte-order-mark

I am trying to create a csv file  with UTF8 with BOM using c++. Can anybody help me, how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put the BOM into a string and write that to your file (using whatever method you're using, e.g. streams or classic cstdio):

```
const char *bom = "\xef\xbb\xbf"; // UTF-8
const char *bom_alt = {0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf, 0}; // the null termination is optional, depending on how you write it later on
```

Then you'll just have to ensure you're actually writing proper UTF-8 and no ANSI or wide char strings. I'd recommend [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) for that (used it in work projects already and works perfectly fine without having to use some huge library such as Boost).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Qt library, you can use `QTextStream::setGenerateByteOrderMark(bool)` to add the BOM.